# More asp.net mvc layouts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

I have been searching some .css layouts for asp.net mvc model.

I like the suggested view, but I want to give a new look to my application just applying a new color scheme.

Someone find some nice schema?

thanks.

Comment: i just found a few layouts in: http://www.asp.net/mvc/gallery/default.aspx?supportsjs=true

anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the color scheme you might want to try Kuler
http://kuler.adobe.com/#themes/newest?time=30

You select the color scheme you like and click on this [click this button http://www.rocketweb.nl/download/adjustcolor.jpg](http://www.rocketweb.nl/download/adjustcolor.jpg) button.
Next you select the hex value and copy/past this in the css file of the MVC application, replacing the original color value. Don't forget about the # character!

Or if you are on this page:
http://kuler.adobe.com/#create/fromacolor.
You can create your own color scheme.